# Change programmatically Woocommerce cart items from virtual to physical

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, virtual, cart

I need to programmatically change a cart item from "virtual" to "physical" at some point in `calculate_cart_item_totals` in Woocommerce. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can only change cart item (product) properties using `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` hook. Now to change a cart item from "virtual" to "physical" you will use [the `WC_Product` method `set_virtual()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.8.0/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1169-L1177) as follows:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_cart_item_data_replacement', 16 );
function custom_cart_item_data_replacement( $cart ) {

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Change virtual cart item to "physical"
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_virtual() ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_virtual(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.